# Angular Help List App

Tags: angularjs

I'm creating an Angular app that adds info to a list but I can't seen to get the item to post. I want the use to add info to the form then the info is then add to the responsive table. I'm not sure if the function for the inputs are correct. Check out my code below.

```
angular.module('LumpSumApp', [])
    .controller('LumpSumController', function() {
        var lumpSumList = this;

        lumpSumList.addLumpSum = function() {
            lumpSumList.lumpsums.push({ select: lumpSumList.lumpSumType, done: false });
            lumpSumList.lumpSumType = '';

            lumpSumList.lumpsums.push({ select: lumpSumList.lumpSumCategory, done: false });
            lumpSumList.lumpSumCategory = '';

            lumpSumList.lumpsums.push({ text: lumpSumList.lumpSumEstimate, done: false });
            lumpSumList.lumpSumEstimate = '';

            lumpSumList.lumpsums.push({ text: lumpSumList.lumpSumExpenses, done: false });
            lumpSumList.lumpSumExpenses = '';

            lumpSumList.lumpsums.push({ file: lumpSumList.lumpSumQuote, done: false });
            lumpSumList.lumpSumQuote = '';

            lumpSumList.lumpsums.push({ file: lumpSumList.lumpSumReceipt, done: false });
            lumpSumList.lumpSumReceipt = '';
        };

    });


<form class="form-inline" ng-submit="lumpSumList.addLumpSum()">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <select class="form-control" ng-model="lumpSumList.lumpSumType">
                                <option>Select a Type</option>
                                <option>2</option>
                                <option>3</option>
                                <option>4</option>
                                <option>5</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <select class="form-control" ng-model="lumpSumList.lumpSumCategory">
                                <option>Select a Category</option>
                                <option>2</option>
                                <option>3</option>
                                <option>4</option>
                                <option>5</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="lumpSumList.lumpSumEstimate" size="40" placeholder="Estimated Expenses">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="lumpSumList.lumpSumExpenses" size="40" placeholder="Actual Expenses">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="btn btn-primary">
                                <i class="fa fa-file-text-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                <input type="file" ng-model="lumpSumList.lumpSumQuote" style="display: none;">
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="btn btn-primary">
                                <i class="fa fa-file-text-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                <input type="file" ng-model="lumpSumList.lumpSumReceipt" style="display: none;">
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="add">
                    </form>


<div class="table-responsive">
                    <table class="table">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Expense Type</th>
                                <th>Expense Category</th>
                                <th>Estimated Expenses</th>
                                <th>Actual Expenses</th>
                                <th>Upload Quote(s)</th>
                                <th>Upload Receipt(s)</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr ng-repeat="lumpsum in lumpSumList.lumpsums">
                                <td>{{lumpSumList.lumpSumType}}</td>
                                <td>{{lumpSumList.lumpSumCategory}}</td>
                                <td>{{lumpSumList.lumpSumEstimate}}</td>
                                <td>{{lumpSumList.lumpSumExpenses}}</td>
                                <td>{{lumpSumList.lumpSumQuote}}</td>
                                <td>{{lumpSumList.lumpSumReceipt}}</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
```

Comment: you are approaching this the wrong way.  first, you don't have `lumpSumList.lumpsums` defined, so you can't push anything into it.  but even if you do define it, you are trying to push a new row for each column, which won't do what you expect, and on top of that, your `ng-repeat` is iterating through the array, but inside the iteration, you are referring to the model values from the dropdowns, not the specific `lumpsum` row, which has a totally different structure.

Comment: every row should be an object, and every object should have all the properties from the dropdowns.  look up `angular.copy()` as well.

Comment: Thanks for the response @Claies, I've looked at angular.copy() but will it generate a new row? https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy

Comment: I didn't use `angular.copy` in my answer, because we are "clearing" all the form fields every time.  `angular.copy` is useful if you wanted to be able to insert multiple rows but didn't want to clear the form each time, or if the items you are inserting are objects themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reworked your code with changes to handle an array of objects.

The two keys here are the changes to the controller code and the changes to the HTML.

In the JavaScript, we first initialize the `lumpSumList.lumpsums` when the controller loads.  Then, inside the function, each time the `addLumpSum` button is clicked, we create a new object to hold all the properties from the dropdowns, then push this object into the array.

In the HTML, we output the `lumpsum` values, rather than the dropdown values.  Just as a quick fix, I also added `value=''` to the default options in the dropdown to get rid of the empty option.

```js
angular.module('LumpSumApp', [])
  .controller('LumpSumController', function() {
    var lumpSumList = this;

    lumpSumList.lumpsums = [];

    lumpSumList.addLumpSum = function() {

      var lumpsum = {
        lumpSumType: lumpSumList.lumpSumType,
        lumpSumCategory: lumpSumList.lumpSumCategory,
        lumpSumEstimate: lumpSumList.lumpSumEstimate,
        lumpSumExpenses: lumpSumList.lumpSumExpenses
      };

      lumpSumList.lumpsums.push(lumpsum);

      lumpSumList.lumpSumType = '';
      lumpSumList.lumpSumCategory = '';
      lumpSumList.lumpSumEstimate = '';
      lumpSumList.lumpSumExpenses = '';
    };

  });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="LumpSumApp">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.x" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.11/angular.min.js" data-semver="1.5.11"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="LumpSumController as lumpSumList">
  <form class="form-inline" ng-submit="lumpSumList.addLumpSum()">
    <div class="form-group">
      <select class="form-control" ng-model="lumpSumList.lumpSumType">
        <option value=''>Select a Type</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
        <option>4</option>
        <option>5</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <select class="form-control" ng-model="lumpSumList.lumpSumCategory">
        <option value=''>Select a Category</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
        <option>4</option>
        <option>5</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="lumpSumList.lumpSumEstimate" size="40" placeholder="Estimated Expenses">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="lumpSumList.lumpSumExpenses" size="40" placeholder="Actual Expenses">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <i class="fa fa-file-text-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <input type="file" ng-model="lumpSumList.lumpSumQuote" style="display: none;">
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <i class="fa fa-file-text-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <input type="file" ng-model="lumpSumList.lumpSumReceipt" style="display: none;">
      </label>
    </div>
    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="add">
  </form>


  <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Expense Type</th>
          <th>Expense Category</th>
          <th>Estimated Expenses</th>
          <th>Actual Expenses</th>
          <th>Upload Quote(s)</th>
          <th>Upload Receipt(s)</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="lumpsum in lumpSumList.lumpsums">
          <td>{{lumpsum.lumpSumType}}</td>
          <td>{{lumpsum.lumpSumCategory}}</td>
          <td>{{lumpsum.lumpSumEstimate}}</td>
          <td>{{lumpsum.lumpSumExpenses}}</td>
          <td>{{lumpsum.lumpSumQuote}}</td>
          <td>{{lumpsum.lumpSumReceipt}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: To add to that let's say I have a budget of $10,000 and every time a new object is added the Actual Expenses is subtracted from the $10,000 buget